# How to update and select a row within one query in SqLite?

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite

I want to update and select one row within one query in SqLite. In MySql my wanted query would look like this:

```
SET @update_id := -1;
UPDATE data SET `Status` = 'running', Id = (SELECT @update_id := Id) 
  WHERE `Status` = 'scheduled' LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM data WHERE id=@update_id;"
```

The above query will set the *Status* to 'running' and the value of the variable *@update_id* to the *Id* of the modified row for the first row that is having *Status* of 'scheduled' and than uses the variable *@update_id* to fetch the complete modified row.

**The important point is that I need to select the row that I had been modified by the UPDATE statement**

But as far as I know SqLite does not support variables.

How can the MySQL query from above be rewritten for SqLite?

Comment: Can you explain what your trying to do here exactly?
It seems your setting Id to the previous value if Id or -1 if its not set?

Comment: Your SQL is actually three statments, not one.

Comment: @mutzel: For concurrency concerns, best I can suggest is a int column with the version.  It means needing to pass the ID and the version when doing something, but it would effectively stop concurrency concerns.

Comment: How about using OMG Ponies answer and changing 3 to
UPDATE DATA SET STATUS = 'running' WHERE ID = ? and status='scheduled';
This would mean the update would fail if someone else modified it. You could then run sqlite3_total_changes() to make sure you made changes, but as mentioned in its documentation sqlite3_total_changes() is not thread safe. Sigh..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [declare and use variables in whatever program you write that runs SQLite statements](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg26594.html).

Thankfully, you can use [bind variables in SQLite](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/blog/2004/october/6.html):

```
//1.  Fetch the id into whatever language you are using:
SELECT id FROM DATA WHERE status = 'scheduled' LIMIT 1;

//2. Retrieve the id value from Step 1's resultset
int id = [id value from the resultset];

//3. Construct the update statement
parsed_sql_stmt stmt = parse_sql(UPDATE DATA SET STATUS = 'running' WHERE ID = ?);

//4. Execute update statement
exec_stmt(stmt, id);

//5. Select everything in the DATA table for that record
stmt = parse_sql(SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE id = ?);
exec_stmt(stmt, id);
```

sheepsimulator is right - this is three separate statements.

Comment: This looks better, but there would be a chance that between 1. and 3. someone else is updating the same row. I thought that this can be easily avoided by finding out which row the UPDATE statement did modify.

Comment: @mutzel: Your concern is valid - a stored procedure would be an option, but SQlite doesn't support this: http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this depends on where you are executing the code.

If you want to use variables when in the commandline interface to SQLite, no, there are no session variables.  Your out of luck there.

If you want to use variables when in a connection to an SQLite database via the official C++ API (or some other API), you'll need to use the [bind variables](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) notation (see 3.0 on that page).

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the Id of the row that will get modified by the UPDATE statement in advance.